# GPS Tracking with Google Maps API v2 and Getting Long. & Latit

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I really need an example about that topic. I tried **LocationListener** method GPS Tracking but it didn't help me. Because i need to get Long. and Latit. at Users every step.(Or maybe 2-3 steps) Could you please help me? (Sorry about my bad english.) *By the way i can see User steps at screen with a blue arrow when i use my application. But i don't know how can i get user's Long. and Latit. information.* Thanks.

Comment: I recommend a good tutorial to you. ===> [Click here: this site is very useful to those who have been interested in the Google Maps. Try to search this site and you will get more information there](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-with-gps-and-locationmanager-in-android/)..And [see this tutorial at there](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-geocoding-showing-user-input-location-on-google-map-android-api-v2/). I hope you will be satisfied with this tutorials.

Comment: kinda helpful. But it still didnt help enough :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code:

```
LocationManger lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, new LocationListener() {
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
Bundle extras) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
} 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use getLatitude() and getLongitude of the class Location

Comment: no no no! not like that. I know all of them already. I need to track Blue dot in maps. I mean i need to get its latit. and long. when it's position change (User position change.)(As u know blue dot is you)